# Correct OS path is not being displayed

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, pythonpath, python-os

I wanted  to get the following path for further processes:

```
C:\Users\zaidd\Documents\Treasure Hunt\1
```

However, after the execution of the following statements I get the following path:

Code:

```py
currentLvl = os.getcwd().split("\\")#[-1]
print(currentLvl)
path = os.getcwd()
cwd = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path, os.pardir))
os.chdir(cwd)
print(path)
print(cwd)
```

Output:

```
['C:', 'Users', 'zaidd']
C:\Users\zaidd
C:\Users
```

Here is the location of my py file just in case it's needed:

```
C:\Users\zaidd\Documents\Treasure Hunt\1\IT-Treasure-Hunt.py
```

Comment: You can get the directory name your script in is via `parent = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you just want the path to the directory containing the running python file. This is the easiest way that I know of:

```py
import pathlib
directory = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
```

In your case, `directory` would end up as `C:\Users\zaidd\Documents\Treasure Hunt\1`